# UIWebView deprecated / WKWebView

Tags: cordova, uiwebview, cordova-plugins, uiwebviewdelegate

On the last publication of my application on the Apple Store, I received the email from Apple saying that "ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - Apple will stop accepting submissions of app updates that use UIWebView APIs starting from December 2020"

I know UIWebView is deprecated and i have to use WKWebView instead.

The plugins used are:

```
>> cordova plugin list
cordova-plugin-appversion 1.0.0 "App Version"
cordova-plugin-battery-status 2.0.2 "Battery"
cordova-plugin-compat 1.0.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-console 1.1.0 "Console"
cordova-plugin-datepicker 0.9.3 "DatePicker"
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.2 "Device"
cordova-plugin-file 4.3.3 "File"
cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.6.3 "File Transfer"
cordova-plugin-network-information 2.0.1 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-qrscanner 3.0.1 "QRScanner"
cordova-plugin-screen-orientation 3.0.1 "Screen Orientation"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.2 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-sqlite-2 1.0.6 "SQLitePlugin"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.2 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"
cordova-sqlite-storage 3.1.0 "Cordova sqlite storage plugin - cordova-sqlite-storage plugin version"
es6-promise-plugin 4.1.0 "Promise"
{}
```

in package.json, "cordova-ios": "^ 5.1.1"

I found the only plugin using UIWebViewDelegate, it is "appversion" but I don't know how to solve the problem (I am newbie with Cordova)

thanks a lot
best regards

Comment: The quick and dirty fix is to remove that plugin if you cannot fork and modify it..